# Apple Developer Program for personal app

Tags: icloud, developer-program

I'm working on a probably-not-to-be-published app that requires a single plist synced between devices. Do I understand it correctly that this *requires* you to join the Apple Developer Program? (Assuming you want to use the native iCloud solution.)

If so … *sigh*. But, besides that, are there any roadblocks I should be aware of? Can I just use my personal Apple ID and sign up? Are there any business-y things I'd have to do?

Answer (score 2):

No. Start with [Xcode on a Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/266340/5472) and a free Apple ID. Only [pay for the developer program](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/90410/5472) when you need test flight or a certificate for longer installations.

Comment: But I need a paid account to do anything with CloudKit right?

Comment: Yes, but cloud kit is almost never needed for small apps. Tons of other more manageable and easier to debug data stores exist @Daan

Comment: Any you would recommend for the simplest of use cases?

Comment: Start with Keychain, then free swift SDK for DynamoDB (Azure and Google have similar offerings) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-swift/latest/developer-guide/getting-started.html really depends what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. I think might go for the paid account anyway because of the cert expirations. I thought it only expired a week after the last build, but it turns out it expires every week *whatever you do*. This might just nudge me towards a paid account.